# Immediately update database on click of radio

Tags: php, forms, onclick, radio-button

I have several forms with radio buttons on a page. My goal is to have the database updated immediately on the click of a radio button. Here is what I have put together so far, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
<? include 'dbconnect.inc.php';?>
<script type="text/javascript">function do_submit(){document.forms['decision'].submit();}</script>

<? $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items");
   while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){ ?>
   <form name='decision' method='post' action='action.php'>
       <label>Keep:</label><input type='radio' name='dec' value='keep' onchange='do_submit()' <? if($row['Dec1']=='keep'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
       <label>Donate:</label><input type='radio' name='dec' value='donate' onchange='do_submit()' <? if($row['Dec1']=='donate'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
       <label>Sell:</label><input type='radio' name='dec' value='sell' onchange='do_submit()' <? if($row['Dec1']=='sell'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
       <label>Trash:</label><input type='radio' name='dec' value='trash' onchange='do_submit()' <? if($row['Dec1']=='trash'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> >
       <label>Give To:</label><input type='text' name='dec' size='15' onchange='do_submit()' <? if($row['Dec1']!='keep' || $row['Dec1']!='donate' || $row['Dec1']!='sell' || $row['Dec1']!='trash'){echo $row['Dec1'];} ?> >
       <input type='hidden' name='Id' value='<? echo $row['Id']; ?>' />
   </form>
   <? } ?>
```

action.php

```
<? $mysqli->query("UPDATE items SET  Dec1 =  '{$_POST['dec']}' WHERE Id = '{$_POST['$Id']}'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); ?>
```

Am I anywhere close? Can someone help me through this?

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but you'd probably want to go with something like this (AJAX + jQuery).  Would need quite a bit added to it to pass all your variables through properly.

```
$(":radio").click(function(){  
    $("#result").html(ajax_load);  
    $.post(  
        loadUrl,  
        {myvariable: "myvalue", myothervariable: "myothervalue"},  
        function(responseText){  
            $("#result").html(responseText);  
        },  
        "html"  
    );  
});
```

Here's a good, supplementary read for you as well:  [5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the first thing about jquery or ajax. Would you have a minute to expand on your suggestion? I know that's asking a lot of you, haha! but I'm lost!

Comment: Here's a basic tutorial on jQuery:  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp.  Read that, then look through the ajax/jquery article I posted in my original answer.  From there, you should be able to start making some sense of what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an ajax onclick event to send the command to your action script.

Inline php is not the way to go.

Comment: At first glance this seems the case, but after I looked again I noticed the Javascript.

Comment: Is the javascript included not enough to pass my variables to the action.php? @deizel : is it possible to tweak my original code to make  this work?

Comment: Yes, your Javascript will submit the form, causing a POST request to action.php. You should be able to confirm this because your browser should take you to action.php. Changing POST to GET will make things clearer as the values will appear in the URL. The other answer suggests doing things asynchronously (Ajax), meaning the page doesn't actually change.